# creating one loop for parsing json data

Tags: php, json, loops, foreach

So I would like to create just one loop to parse the json data i have. I can successfully parse it in 2 foreach loops however when trying to combine in one loop using $key => $value the $key returns nothing when called. How can I successfully take the 2 foreach loops I have here and combine them into one?

```
$contents = file_get_contents($url);

$results = json_decode($contents, true);

$jsonList = $results['genres'];


foreach($jsonList as $key) {

$GenreID = $key['id'].'<br>';

echo $GenreID;
}


foreach($jsonList as $key => $value) {

$GenreName = $value['name'].'<br><br>';

echo $GenreName;
}
```

The json data is as follows:

```
{"genres":[{"id":28,"name":"Action"},{"id":12,"name":"Adventure"},{"id":16,"name":"Animation"},{"id":35,"name":"Comedy"},{"id":80,"name":"Crime"},{"id":99,"name":"Documentary"},{"id":18,"name":"Drama"},{"id":10751,"name":"Family"},{"id":14,"name":"Fantasy"},{"id":36,"name":"History"},{"id":27,"name":"Horror"},{"id":10402,"name":"Music"},{"id":9648,"name":"Mystery"},{"id":10749,"name":"Romance"},{"id":878,"name":"Science Fiction"},{"id":10770,"name":"TV Movie"},{"id":53,"name":"Thriller"},{"id":10752,"name":"War"},{"id":37,"name":"Western"}]}
```

Comment: no need to have 2, just use `$value['id']` and `$value['name']`

Comment: you are awesome, thanks Ghost! That is exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can still use `$key` as an index when also extracting the `$value`.

However note that you shouldn't be assigning the line breaks to your variables, and should instead consider them part of the view by echoing them out independently:

```
$contents = file_get_contents($url);
$results = json_decode($contents, true);
$jsonList = $results['genres'];

foreach($jsonList as $key => $value) {
  $GenreID = $key['id']; // Depending on structure, you may need $value['id'];
  $GenreName = $value['name'];
  echo $GenreID . '<br>';
  echo $GenreName . '<br><br>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Your single loop below here.

 foreach($jsonList as $key)
  {
 $GenreID = $key['id'].'<br>';
  echo $GenreID;
 $GenreName = $value['name'].'<br><br>'; 
echo $GenreName;
 }

$key is a assosative array.Therefore it had some index.So you can use this index in single loop.
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you get confused over your data structure. Seeing the json, the resulting "$jsonlist" supposed to contain array with id and value as keys.

You can iterate over it and extract the the appropriate key.

Myabe something like this:

```
foreach($jsonlist as $value) {
    echo "id: " . $value['id'] . "\n";
    echo "name: " . $value['name'] . "\n";
}
```

extra bonus, if you want to create 1 level array from your json based on id with the name you could try array reduce using anon function like this:

`$jsonlist = array_reduce($jsonlist, function($result, $item){
    $result[$item['id']] = $item['name'];
    return $result;
}, []);`

extra neat for transformation of static structure data.